# Are US treasuries volatile and liquid enough for trading short term investment?

Tags: united-states, online-trading, treasury

If I buy one bond (or bill, note) for 100.0 ($1000), is it common for its market price to go for 104.0 ($1040) within few days, so I sell it and make profit of $40 (which is more than its yield) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 4% jump in US Treasury yields in a few days would be ***extremely unusual***. There have been times or rapid inflation where rates have jumped 4% over several months, but that has not happened since the early 1980s.

If you're looking to make 4% profit over small time periods, then bonds (and especially Treasuries) are not the place to do that.

Comment: @D Stanley you meant 4% down in yield (becaue the treasury/bond price was 4% up), right?

Comment: @D Stanley the bond price is depends on sell/buy demand like in other secuirities (stocks..etc), right? the buy demand which raised its price could/could not be because the rates are higher...am I misunderstand it?

Comment: just basing it on supply/demand is too simplistic. the value of these bonds is determined from the market's view of interest rates. So the _entire market_ would need to think that interest rates will be 4% higher. That belief would most likely be based in reality somehow.

Comment: @D Stanley if a stock market fall due to financial crisis,pandemic...etc and all traders go to bonds, wouldn't this increase the prices of bonds?

Comment: possibly, but interest rates are at historic lows, and investors buy bonds either to get interest or to speculate on rates going _down_. Both of those seem highly unlikely in a low-rate environment.

Comment: @DStanley or as an alternative to stocks that are expected to go down even more